# What does "用意する身にもなれっての" in this dialogue mean?

Tags: translation

I'm still fairly a novice and I just came across the word "身になる" which apparently has several meanings. I looked up the word online to look for more examples. I came across this on a blog:

> いつもいつも
>   当たり前みたいに毎週泊まりに来て
>   用意する身にもなれっての

From what I can tell this was posted by an office lady venting about her boyfriend.

I'm unfortunately confused with the last line "用意する身にもなれっての".

The best translation I can come up with is "Try to imagine what it's like from my side, preparing (something?) for you."

That's most likely wrong so I'll take any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your translation for 身になる is correct. And by 用意, she simply refers to preparation to accept that person as a guest to her house. This may involve preparing food, a bed etc. Less ambiguously, it would be something like

> 「泊{と}める用意{ようい}をする身{み}にもなれ」

or

> 「おもてなしの用意{ようい}をする身{み}にもなれ」

or something to that effect. This could have a different meaning in a more specific context, but in most situations this is what it would denote.